# How to change smarty template variables from a plugin without touching the original template file

Tags: php, smarty

Here is the problem:

1- I have a smarty templates each called products.tpl. About 5 files, each one of those is different than the other in the presentation code. They all present the same variables and have the same name but in different directories.

2- I don't have access to the application code that provide the variables for these templates. So i cant change or alter these variables in the original application.

3- I need to check some of the variables and return different code that depends on the values of the variables.

4- I do not want to touch the template files. want its code to be the same. i do not want to execute the plugin functions from templates.

I want the plugin to check smarty template before output and if the template is named "products.tpl" and in certain path, the plugin check the variables sent to this template and modify the template code and return that code to output.

It maybe look like template override or Prefilters plugin. but I don't know if this possible and how to start.

Code Example:

smarty template file products.tpl:

```
<td valign="top" class="textright" nowrap>

{if $product.bid}
{if $product.displayprice}<span class="pricing">{$product.displayprice}</span><br />{/if}
</td>
```

I want to change the product price variable without touching this template code using a plugin. is it possible?

Comment: if you can't touch neither the PHP, nor the template files, I don't think you can do something about it. If you did have access to the PHP code, you could load a pre- or post- filter to do some parsing and replacing

Comment: i tried to do the pre filter plugin but it is not loaded. is there is a way to load it from smarty files. other php files of the applications are encoded.

Comment: I don't think you can load it from smarty.